# Rotate text at button click event

Tags: javascript, css

I need to rotate a text at different angles at button click.

I need two button, one to move text clockwise and other to move text anticlockwise.

Comment: Please don't tag this as `[php]`, since PHP cannot be used for this purpose. CSS, on the other hand, can. Using appropriate tags will get you better answers.

Comment: this one works for you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452477/rotate-div-text-after-clicking-on-button-using-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 4):

try this:

html:

```
<input id="rotateBtn" type="submit" value="rotate"/>
<div class="textToRotate">text to be rotated</div>
```

css ( tip: use transform-origin to control rotation anchor point, here used only for webkit )

```
.rotate {
-moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
 -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
 -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 ;
 filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /*IE6,IE7 */
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)";  /* IE8 */
 }
```

jQuery on document ready:

```
 $('#rotateBtn').click(function() {
     $('.textToRotate').addClass('rotate');
 });
```

check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/YZY8J/2/

---

update: each click  increments 20degrees: http://jsfiddle.net/SebastianPataneMasuelli/YZY8J/5/

Comment: Hello I have tried this code its just move text one time when we click rotate button.i need like when when i click first time its move 20 degree further increment on second time of click

Comment: it only works on -webkit, but you get the idea, also, you don't need any of the css anymore

Comment: hey, i was sleeping, what's the issue?

Answer (score 3):

I am giving the answer of my own question.I find out the exactly what I want just because of you guys.You all helped me alot.

Thanks

```
     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .square {
               width: 144px;
               height: 144px;
               background: #fff;
               margin-right: 48px;
               float: left;
                   }

             .transformed {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
          -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
           transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
                       }
          </style>
          <script type="text/javascript">

             function change(txt){
                    var d = document.getElementById('derg').value || 0;

                     var dd = parseInt(d)+parseInt(txt);

                    document.getElementById('derg').value=dd;
                    var a=dd+'deg';


                  document.getElementById('tdiv4').style.MozTransform = 'rotate('+a+')';
         }

                 </script>




           <div id="tdiv4" class="square" >this is tdiv4</div>

          <input type="hidden" value="" id="derg">
         <input type="button" onclick="change(15)" value="change"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, [read an article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation) on using CSS3 transforms to rotate text.

Next:

1. Use JavaScript to register click handlers on your buttons.
2. In your click handlers, use JavaScript to either directly modify the necessary CSS attributes on the text in question, or apply a new CSS class based on a computed angle (with predefined CSS classes for every angle you wish to support).

Comment: I have study about rotation using css but i need this at run time mean for visitors.when user click on button its move clockwise at particular angle

Comment: JavaScript executes 'at run time' on the visitor's web browser. Web pages can be dynamic. When the user clicks the button, JavaScript manipulates the properties of the objects on the page and the browser updates the result immediately for the user. This does not go back to the server.

Comment: You might find this article helpful: http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html

Comment: I have clarified my answer to indicate that JavaScript is what you would be doing this in.

Comment: <style type="text/css" media="screen">
.square {
    width: 144px;
    height: 144px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 48px;
    float: left;
}

.transformed {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
    transform: rotate(15deg) scale(1.25, 0.5);
}
</style>

Comment: hello sir i want show my code may i.actually rotation done but having bit issue .please reply its urgent.Ur article help me more to do this  .Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery Animations](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) that'll do just about anything you want